# Automating web projects start in mac

Tags: automation, web

I would like to know if there is any way of automating my workflow when creating websites.

I know that there were apps that did this, but I can't find them anymore(envato's builder).

What I do when starting a new web design project is always the same, I download the latest version of HTML5 Boilerplate or bootstrap, copy it to a folder, then I change a bit the structure of the folders and copy some pre written js.

I currently use OSX El capitan.
Thank ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is very helpful to automate repetitive tasks. But there are lots of alternatives, like e. g. [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

Grunt, for example,  can do things like linting (error checking), unit testing, minifying JavaScript and CSS, compiling CSS preprocessor files (LESS, SASS) and much more.

Maybe you should look out for a package manager like [Bower](https://bower.io/), too. It will help you to keep the dependencies of your project up to date.